# Cannot load the data from SQL Server database to Crystal Reports c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am working with Crystal Reports in C# using a SQL Server database, I cannot proceed with my project because I am getting an error

> Load Save Report Exception

on the line which I am going to set the data source of my Crystal report.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
string conString = @"data source =JR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog = election;integrated security =true;";
string sql = "Select can_names,can_pos,partylist,num_votes from tbl_Candidates";

con = new SqlConnection(conString);
con.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
ReportPracice._DATASETS.DataSet1 ds = new ReportPracice._DATASETS.DataSet1();
da.Fill(ds, "tbl_Candidates");

MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count.ToString()); //Returns a value of "40";
con.Close();

ReportPracice._REPORTS.CrystalReport1 rpt = new ReportPracice._REPORTS.CrystalReport1();
rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]); //in this line, where I am getting that error.
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "0" instead of "1"....

C# indexes are zero based, not 1 based.

ds.Tables[0]

or

ds.Tables["tbl_Candidates"]

or check the name

```
string tName = ds.Tables[1].TableName;
```

I know you're pushing out a RowCount on "1".

When in doubt, do a

```
string temp = ds.GetXml();
```

and get the value of temp and look at it.
That always tells the story.

If you have a strongly typed DataSet, then you shouldn't be using cardinal number references.  ("0", or "1", etc).  Use the names of the tables.

Then check the report to see which dataset(table) is being references.  You may have to open the report in notepad and fish around.

The way you are doing the tablename(s) of the dataset's is "loosey goosey", and there is probably a mismatch in the names somewhere.